# How to get rid of the page number

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I customized my footer so that the page number will be on the right side of the footer instead of its default location which is the center of the footer. When I generated my file, the page number appeared on both the right side and the center. How do I get rid of the page number in the center?

Also, how do I get rid of the header?

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{\textsf{www.economics-ejournal.org}}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
Content here.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a minimal working example!

Comment: Add `\fancyhf{}` after `\pagestyle{fancy}`

Comment: @percusse: I did not check what Haris Kumar proposed, I referred to Reg' statement, that it worked ;-)

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Converting my comment in to answer, just to close this.</sub>

When you define and apply a `fancy` page style, you need to empty the previous values/definitions of headers and footers. This is done by issuing

```
\fancyhf{}
```

in the definition as

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}        %% <--- here
\lfoot{\textsf{www.economics-ejournal.org}}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

After this, your problem should go away.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, for your requirements the answer provided by Harish Kumar should be sufficient. As an alternative, following two lines can replace `\lfoot` and `\rfoot` commands in that answer:

```
\fancyfoot[L]{\textsf{www.economics-ejournal.org}}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
```